# Execute commands from typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, gulp

I want to execute command on the server on which **angularjs2** application using **typescript** is deployed. Commands are simple like:

```
java --version
```

and want to get response of the command.

I don't know, is it possible or not.

Thanks in Advance!!

Edit:
Getting error:

```
zone.js:260 Uncaught EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:8:48
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: require is not defined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at AppComponent.performCmdOperation (http://localhost:8000/app/app.component.js:43:67)
```

and

> app.component.ts

is

```
export class AppComponent{

SelectType = EnumSelectType;
selectedSection: SelectType = EnumSelectType[EnumSelectType.Home];
selectPage(selectType:EnumSelectType) {
    console.log('Global : ' + EnumSelectType[selectType]);
    this.selectedSection = EnumSelectType[selectType];
    console.log(this.selectedSection + ' selected');
}

performCmdOperation(){
    console.log('in perform action');
    const exec = require('sdk/system/child_process').exec; //this is the point where I'm getting error.
    exec('ipconfig', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
            return;
        }
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    });
}
```

Please help me finding the issue. Is there any `import missing or any dependency` required for using **'child_process'**.

My current dependencies are

```
"bootstrap": "^3.3.6",

"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",

"systemjs": "0.19.27",
"es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"zone.js": "^0.6.12"
```

If this is something for which need to modify **gulpfile.ts**. Please instruct how 'child_process' will added in gulpfile.

Comment: what are you using on server? node, php, java,,,?

Comment: I'm using node.js for server.

Comment: How is that related to Angular2? Only because it is served from the same server?

Comment: I'm using type script for angular 2 application. That's why, I mentioned Angular2 in description, not in the Question title.